# Asterisk 11.7.0: Call goes through when dialed directly, but not from IVR

Tags: asterisk

I have a specific Dial(SIP/number@carrier) line in an IVR in my dial plan. With one specific number I get "your call cannot be completed as dialed" or a fast busy. On the rarest of occasions the call does go through. However, if I call directly from my SIP phone, the call goes through every time. There are no messages in the CLI (with vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv) either.

What could be the difference between a call dialed through an IVR and a call dialed from a simple outbound dial plan?

Comment: There are no way do dial directly. All calls in asterisk will go via dialplan.

Comment: You are correct. I wasn't thinking clearly. Which now raises an even BIGGER question lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the destination number did not like the caller ID since when I was calling my IVR internally the outbound call received my internal extension as CID.